# linq to entities orderby strange issue

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

maybe foolish question, first times with linq to entities (well, linq in general).

table with id(int), value(decimal), name(string)

for each record i need

> ```
> id
> list<string>
>     id
>     value
>     name
> ```

THE FOLLOWING WORKS FINE

```
int pageSize=10
int pageIndex=2
var data = (from c in db.Customers
            orderby c.ID
            select new { c.ID, c.Value, c.Name }
             ).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

but doesn'organize the data in the way i need them. However the results are like:

1    100    name A

2    300    name B

3    200    name C

4    100    name D

THE FOLLOWING MAKE ME MAD

```
int pageSize=10
int pageIndex=2
var data2 = (from c in db.Customers
             orderby c.ID
             select new
             {
                  id = c.ID,
                  cell = new List<string> { 
                     SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.ID), 
                     SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.Value), 
                     c.Name
                     }
             }
       ).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

which brings

1

```
     1        100     name A
```

2

```
     name B   300     2
```

3

```
     3        200     name C
```

4

```
     name D   100     4
```

and so on...

i can't understand why, and how to solve it without writing lenghty code i would skip with love.

Help please,
Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why your code doesn't work, but try using `ToString` instead of `SqlFunction` like:

```
int pageSize = 10;
int pageIndex = 2;
var data = (from c in db.Customers
            orderby c.ID
            select new
            {
                c.ID, 
                cell = new List<string>{ c.ID.ToString(), c.Value.ToString(), c.Name }
            }).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

or

```
var ordered = db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.ID);
var page = orderedCustomers.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

var projection = page.Select(c => new
                 {
                     c.ID,
                     cell = new List<string> { c.ID.ToString(), c.Value.ToString(), c.Name }
                 }).ToArray();
```

**Update:** I see you can't get Linq to Entity work with your strings. But you can do it locally then :) try:

```
var ordered = db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.ID);
var page = orderedCustomers.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

var local = page.AsEnumerable();

var projection = local.Select(c => new
                 {
                     c.ID,
                     cell = new List<string> { c.ID.ToString(), c.Value.ToString(), c.Name }
                 }).ToArray();
```

Comment: First off, thank you for this fix (+1). Second - what a stupid problem. I wish this would be fixed by the .NET team (can it be fixed?). Caused me a considerable headache.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i followed your second sample, separating linq to entities from linq, and used tostring()
Writing all in one sentence i couldn't us to string, entities doesn't support it.

Still i would like to know the logic for the result shuffle i got, is scary and illogic

Tks for your quick answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. I thought Linq to Entity would work with `ToString`. But a solution is simple, I'll update my answer in a couple of minutes. (another time, you should post a comment and not a answer)