# JSON results are returned in a different order than expected

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities, jqgrid, dynamic-linq

I am following [Phil Haack's example on using jQuery Grid with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx). I have it working and it works well...except for one minor problem. When I sort the columns by something other than the ID, the JSON data returned from the server is very...well...wrong. Here's is my Controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PeopleData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = repository.FindAllPeople().Count();
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    var people = repository.FindAllPeople()
        .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
        .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize);

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (
            from person in people
            select new
            {
                i = person.PersonID,
                cell = new List<string> { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) person.PersonID), person.PersonName }
            }
        ).ToArray()
    };

    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

When I sort by PersonID in the jsGrid table, I get this data back (I just used the name of the current ID as the name - e.g. 1, One; 2, Two, etc.)

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":6,"rows":[{"i":1,"cell":[" 1","One"]},{"i":2,"cell":["         2","Two"]},{"i":3,"cell":["         3","Three"]},{"i":4,"cell":["         4","Four"]},{"i":5,"cell":["         5","Five"]},{"i":6,"cell":["         6","Six"]}]}
```

When I sort by PersonName, however, every other row has the order (the ID vs. the name) flipped around. So when I show it in the table, the PersonName is in the ID column and the ID is in the person column. Here is the JSON result.

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":6,"rows":[{"i":5,"cell":[" 5","Five"]},{"i":4,"cell":["Four","    4"]},{"i":1,"cell":["         1","One"]},{"i":6,"cell":["Six","      6"]},{"i":3,"cell":["         3","Three"]},{"i":2,"cell":["Two","    2"]}]}
```

Anybody have any insight into what I've done wrong that causes this to happen?

**Update**

So, I have learned that, what is happening, is that my array values are flipping for every other item in the array. For example...if I populate my database with:

> [A, B, C]

then for every even-numbered result (or odd, if you're counting from 0), my data is coming back:

> [C, B, A]

So, ultimately, my JSON row data is something like:

> [A, B, C]
>   [C, B, A]
>   [A, B, C] 
>   [C, B, A] 
>   ...etc

This is always happening and always consistent. I am going a bit crazy trying to figure out what's going on because it seems like it should be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [linq to entities orderby strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646337/linq-to-entities-orderby-strange-issue/3646373#3646373)

The issue ultimately stems from the fact that Linq to Entities has trouble handling strings. When I was using the SqlFunctions.StringConvert method, this was incorrectly performing the conversion (although, I must admit that I don't fully understand why the order was then switched around).

In either case, per the above post, the solution for fixing the problem was to do the selection locally so that I could "force" Linq to Entities to work with strings properly. From this, my final code is:

```
var people = repository.FindAllPeople()
             .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
             .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
             .Take(pageSize);

// Due to a problem with Linq to Entities working with strings,
// all string work has to be done locally.
var local = people.AsEnumerable();
var rowData = local.Select(person => new
        {
            id = person.PersonID,
            cell = new List<string> { 
                person.PersonID.ToString(),
                person.PersonName
            }
        }
    ).ToArray();

var jsonData = new
{
    total = totalPages,
    page = page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = rowData
};

return Json(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my data which are INT type.
If elements in my queue (A,B,C) are NVARCHAR type I do not have this problem.
So problem is obviously in SqlFunction.StringConvert function.

Comment: You are very close to the right answer (and this eventually lead me to the correct answer). See my response for the final solution. I would give you a +1 for helping me out, but, as a Steelers fan, I can't.

Comment: ;-) Haha...just kidding. +1. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121). If you use fields instead of properties in the `repository.FindAllPeople()` you should look at the commented part of the code where are used `FieldInfo` and `GetField` instead of `PropertyInfo` and `GetProperty`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. (I could be doing something wrong, but I couldn't get it to work.) Something that is interesting is that my data error is consistent. For example: ([1,One], [Two,2], [3,Three], [Four,4]). The names/numbers flip on every other.

Comment: @JasCav: Could you include definition of the class to which has `PersonID` property? Moreover I don't understand from your code why you use `var scenarios = repository.FindAllPeople()...` and then use `from person in **people**` (`people` and not `scenarios`)? One more remark you should replace `i = person.PersonID` to `id = person.PersonID`. Currently `i` will be ignored and as `id` will be used integers like 1,2,3...

Comment: Type on the **scenarios** vs. **people**. Fixed that. I also changed to `id = person.PersonID`, although that doesn't seem to make much difference. As for the class that contains PersonID - it is of type "Person" and is generated using Linq to Entities (EF4). PersonID happens to be an integer (self-incrementing key) in the database.

Comment: @JasCav: From your comment I don't understand whether the problem is fixed or not. About `PersonID` I want only know whether it is a property of a field of the class. Do you tried the sorting from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121 after all the changes from **scenarios** to **people**?

Comment: The scenarios to people was just a typo on SO. It was not a problem in my code. PersonID is a property (an integer) within the Person class. (Again, I don't handle this code - it is generated completely by the Entity Framework.)